# Shell Script to run till data base value gets updated

Tags: shell

db2 connect to DB
STATUS=$(db2 "SELECT STATUS FROM XYZ )
echo $STATUS

Initially the status value will be '4' or 'NOT YET RUN'.

The Shell script has to run until the status value is updated with '0' in data base and exit.

Comment: ...and the question is...? (Besides, this sounds awfully like busy-polling. Perhaps have the database *trigger* a script to run when the status changes?)

Comment: and, please, post the code you wrote until now.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
until [ STATUS="$(db2 "SELECT STATUS FROM XYZ")" && $STATUS = 0 ]
do
   # put rest of the code in this loop.
done
```